# Multiprocessing nested numerical integrals in python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm working with nested numerical integrals in python where the limits of each layer depends on the next layer out. The overall structure of my code looks like

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si

def func(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return x1**2 - x2**3+x3*x2 - x4*x3**3  

def int1():
    """integrates `int2` over x1"""
    a1, b1 = -1, 3
    def int2(x1):
        """integrates `func` over x2 at given x1.""" 
        #partial_func1 = lambda x2: func(x1, x2)
        b2 = 1 - np.abs(x1)
        a2 = -np.abs(x1**3)
        def int3(x2):
            a3 = x2
            b3 = -a3
            def int4(x3):
                partial_func = lambda x4: func(x1, x2, x3, x4)
                a4 = 1+np.abs(x3)
                b4 = - a4
                return si.quad(partial_func,a4,b4)[0]
            return si.quad(int4, a3, b3)[0]
        return si.quad(int3, a2, b2)[0]     
    return si.quad(int2, a1, b1)[0]
result = int1()  # -22576720.048151683
```

In the full version of my code, the integral and the limits are complex and it takes several hours to run, which is inconvenient. Each integral seems like it could be easily parallelized though: it seems like I should be able to use multiprocessing to distribute the integration to multiple CPUs and speed up the run time.

Referring to some other posts on stack overflow, I tried the following:

```
def testfunc(intfunc,fmin,fmax):
    return scint.quad(intfun,fmin,fmax,epsabs=10**-40)[0]

result = pool.map(partial(partial(testfunc, intfunc = int4),fmin = a3),[b3])
```

But I got an error that the local object can't be pickled.

Another resource I came across was at http://catherineh.github.io/programming/2016/10/04/parallel-integration-for-mere-mortals

But I need a function where I can pass the limits through as inputs as well (hence my use of partials).

Does anyone know how to resolve these issues? I think a solution would be some version of pool.map that could handle multiple inputs would be great, but if there's something wrong with my use of partials, that would be great to find out too.

Thanks in advance and let me know if there's anything here that can be cleared up!

Comment: As in the example code I gave, the limits of each inner layer depends on the result of the outer layer. If they're global functions, the limits can't be processed as floats and the integrals can't be evaluated numerically

Comment: How would that resolve what I mentioned with the limits? Just like in written nested integrals, they need to be evaluated sequentially

Comment: I could be well off, I might learn a thing or two here :) The final result should be `-22576720.048151683`?

Comment: That's what this evaluated to last time I ran it!

Comment: Ok, I see your battle here :) I've struggled to rearrange your code to not be nested. It's a huge climb to be able to multiprocess nested functions, possibly even impossible. Plus, your time is spent processing in `scipy` which shouldn't have the GIL restrictions. I don't think this can be done, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It's an unfortunate function of the quantity I need to compute, I promise I'm the most frustrated by this! I was working on some ideas for this, would it be possible to break up my integration range (a1,b1) using np.linspace and then multiprocess each of those separate pieces? I'd need to be able to write something (maybe with partials) that would take the multiple inputs though. Would be great if there was a clear way to do that

Comment: Unfortunately this is beyond me I think. But the gist of my last comment was that as long as you don't have `for` loops and you're utilising `scipy`, I don't think you're being so restricted by processing capability. Multiprocessing makes sense if your code is python-bound (where it's only going to run on one core), but your heavy listing is done in scipy so it's probably running as fast as it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

After much testing and restructuring, it seems that the best way to take care of this is not to nest the functions or the definitions, but rather to make use of the args parameter in the scipy.integrate.quad function to pass external variables through to inner integrations.

Many thanks to those who commented!

Answer (score 0):

This answer probably isn't satisfactory, but hopefully it'll give some insight into what field the question falls.

To reiterate, the original problem is to compute the quadruple integral

```
integrate(
    integrate(
        integrate(
            integrate(
                f(x1, x2, x3, x4),
                [1+abs(x3), -1-abs(x3)]
                ),
            [x2, -x2]
            ),
         [1-abs(x1), -x1**3]
         ),
    [-3, 1])
```

Mathematically, one could formulate this as

```
integrate(f(x1, x2, x3, x4), Omega)
```

where `Omega` is a four-dimensional domain defined by the integral limits above. Had the domain been in one, two, or three dimensions, then the answer to your question would be clear:

1. Discretize your complex domain into lines, triangles, or tetrahedra (those are the simplices in dimensions 1, 2, 3, respectively) (using [one](http://gmsh.info/) [of](https://github.com/nschloe/frentos)  [many](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr) [mesh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MeshPy) [tools](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh)), and then
2. use numerical quadrature on each of the lines/triangles/tetrahedra (e.g., from [here](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy)).

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any tool that discretizes a four-dimensional domain into 4-simplices, nor of quadrature rules for 4-simplices (except perhaps the vertex and midpoint rules). Both, however, would be possible to create in general; particularly a bunch of quadrature rules should be easy to come up with.

For the sake of completeness, let me mention that there is at least one class of domains for which integration rules exist in any dimension: the hypercube.